# Does anyone know how to symmetrize $\gamma$-matrices?

Tags: string-theory, mathematical-physics, dirac-matrices, supergravity

I'm trying to construct the SO(5, 5) $\gamma$-matrices which are real and symmetric. Recently, I have 6 symmetric and 4 antisymmetric $\gamma$-matrices ($6_S + 4_A$ representation). How can I transform (or symmetrize) them to $10_S + 0_A$ representation?

Comment: Which $6_S + 4_A$ representation?

Comment: SO(5,5) gammas are 32*32, right? Since I use Majorana-Weyl spinors, I can reduce the matrices to 16*16. Thus, here I only talk about 16*16 gammas (all real but 6 symmetric and 4 antisymmetric). Does it make sense? If not what do you mean by "which rep"?